# sed replace slash

Tags: linux, sed

am using

```
!/bin/bash
     for fl in *.txt; do
     mv $fl $fl.old
     sed 's/files.php?file=/file/g' $fl.old > $fl
     rm -f $fl.old
     done
```

I need the output replaced with file/  not only file , 
couldnt figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
sed 's/files.php?file=/file\//g;' $fl.old > $fl
```

Notice the `\` used to escape the `/` after `file` in the replacement ...

Answer (score 6):

You can use `#` or `|` instead of `/` to make life easier when using slashes in patterns:

```
!/bin/bash
     for fl in *.txt; do
     mv $fl $fl.old
     sed 's#files.php?file=#file/#g' $fl.old > $fl
     rm -f $fl.old
     done
```

This keeps you from having to escape all the slashes you want to match or use as a replacement like `\/`

Also, just to be clear:

`/` is a slash

`\` is a backslash

Answer (score 1):

You can use escaping of the backslash:

```
sed 's/files.php?file=/file\//g' $fl.old > $fl
```

And that will produce desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't haver to use `/` with sed you can use something else like `#` or `|`

```
sed 's#files.php?file=#file/#g'
```

or

```
sed 's|files.php?file=|file/|g'
```